# Sqlite - creating query for search - begins with then includes

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to create a query in sqlite that will return:
Begins with and then Includes

So "bou" would return:

Bounce
Bounce Back
About Me
Thinking About You
etc.

I've tried combining queries by using unions with LIKE 'search%' and LIKE '%search%', with and without ORDER BY,
but I can't figure it out. I was hoping for something fast and efficient, short of creating 2 different queries/results and combining manually.
Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Why `LIKE '%search%'` does not work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the following may do what you wish or something close to what you wish :-

```
WITH cte1(search_item) AS (SELECT 'bou') -- <<<<<<<<<< search argument
SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN mytext LIKE (select search_item FROM cte1)||'%'
            THEN mytext||' - begins with '||(select search_item FROM cte1)
        ELSE 
            mytext||' - includes '||(select search_item FROM cte1)
    END AS phrased,
    mytext
FROM mytable 
WHERE mytext LIKE '%'||(select search_item FROM cte1)||'%';
```

So using the following as a test :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytable;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable (mytext TEXT);
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES
    ('Bounce'),
    ('Bounce Back'),
    ('About Me'),
    ('About You'),
    ('Something Else'), -- ADDED to prove not found result
    ('Thinking About You')
;

WITH cte1(search_item) AS (SELECT 'bou') -- <<<<<<<<<< search argument
SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN mytext LIKE (select search_item FROM cte1)||'%'
            THEN mytext||' - begins with '||(select search_item FROM cte1)
        ELSE 
            mytext||' - includes '||(select search_item FROM cte1)
    END AS phrased,
    mytext
FROM mytable 
WHERE mytext LIKE '%'||(select search_item FROM cte1)||'%';
```

Results in :-

[image]

However, the following may be more along the lines of what you want (i.e. ordered according whether or not the found data begins with or includes the sreach argument ) :-

```
WITH 
    cte1(search_item) AS (
            SELECT 'bou' -- <<<<<<<<<< search argument
        ), 
    cte2(phrased,ordering,mytext) AS (
            SELECT 
                CASE
                    WHEN mytext LIKE (select search_item FROM cte1)||'%'
                        THEN mytext||' - begins with '||(select search_item FROM cte1)
                    ELSE 
                        mytext||' - includes '||(select search_item FROM cte1)
                END AS phrased,
                    CASE
                    WHEN mytext LIKE (select search_item FROM cte1)||'%'
                        THEN 0
                    ELSE 1
                END AS ordering,
                mytext
            FROM mytable 
            WHERE mytext LIKE '%'||(select search_item FROM cte1)||'%'
        )
    SELECT mytext, phrased FROM cte2 ORDER BY ordering;
;
```

Which results in :-

[image]

Comment: This is amazing - Thank you